# Ошибка AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'priceChangePercent' при работе с binance

Tags: python, криптография, binance

Есть вот такой код, который я копипастнул и у меня он не работает, а в обучающем видео всё ок. Помогите разобраться.

```
from binance.client import Client
import keys
import pandas as pd
import time

client = Client(keys.api_key, keys.secret_key)

def top_coin():
    all_tickers = pd.DataFrame(client.get_all_tickers())
    usdt = all_tickers[all_tickers.symbol.str.contains('USDT')]
    work = usdt[~((usdt.symbol.str.contains('UP')) | (usdt.symbol.str.contains('DOWN')))]
    top_coin = work[work.priceChangePercent == work.priceChangePercent.max()]
    top_coin = top_coin.symbol.values[0]
    return top_coin

print(top_coin())
```

А вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manjaros_clone/PycharmProjects/python_binance_bot/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(top_coin())
  File "/home/manjaros_clone/PycharmProjects/python_binance_bot/main.py", line 12, in top_coin
    top_coin = work[work.priceChangePercent == work.priceChangePercent.max()]
  File "/home/manjaros_clone/PycharmProjects/python_binance_bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5907, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'priceChangePercent'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Я подозреваю, что в обучающем видео колонку priceChangePercent создавали из имеющихся колонок, а вы этот момент пропустили. Но в любом случае попробуйте сделать print(work.columns) и покажите, что вывелось.

Comment: Как домой приду обязательно попробую. Что интересно, этот код работает на windows, но вот отказывается на manjaro, хотя вероятно дело не в этом.

Comment: /home/manjaros_clone/PycharmProjects/python_binance_bot/venv/bin/python /home/manjaros_clone/PycharmProjects/python_binance_bot/main.py 
Index(['symbol!!!!!!!!', 'price!!!!!!!!'], dtype='object')

Comment: Такой вот ответ на print(work.columns)

Comment: Ну вот там всего две эти колонки, никакого priceChange там нет. Стоп, а откуда оно там возьмётся, если вы сами выше отобрали только колонки, где есть строка UP или DOWN.

Comment: Я хз, я просто скопировал код. Причём говорю же на винде работает, а на манжаро шлёт нафиг.

Comment: Вот я олень! Стыдно капец! Сорян ребят, по моей невнимательности была глупейшая ошибка в коде. Когда печатал доверился автоподбору и не перепроверил. В теле функции в первой строчке у меня было all_tickers = pd.DataFrame(client.get_all_tickers()), а должно быть all_tickers = pd.DataFrame(client.get_ticker())